# What is the significance of the cat in the movie "Gone Girl"?

Tags: analysis, gone-girl

Throughout the movie "Gone Girl", there is an orange house cat that appears in numerous scenes. Is this some kind of symbolism?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to initially be a nod to a well-known book on screenwriting. The book has some very specific advice when it comes to getting an audience to side with a character.

In a [2014 interview at the NY Film Festival](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/09/26/gone-girl-premiere_n_5891804.html), ***Gone Girl*** author/screenwriter Gillian Flynn had this to say when questioned about the movie's "cat character":

> *There’s a screenplay book called **Save the Cat**. It’s all about making your character likable. In the first 10 minutes he should do
>   something that makes you like him. I enjoyed that in the first 10
>   minutes [of **Gone Girl**], he literally saves the cat. I love that
>   he’s so devoted to his cat.*

So directly from the source, that appears to be the reason for ***Gone Girl***'s feline featured player. Some critical theories argue that the cat functions onscreen as an impartial third party to the action, viewing events dispassionately from a distance. However, no comment from any of the creative forces involved in the film has ever confirmed this theory, or even mentioned it.